# The longitude and latitude always return zero using gps android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, gps

I am using the following code to get my current location. But the problem I am facing is, it always returns 0.0 for latitude and longitude in the case of Gps. The network provider is working correctly. . I have turned on the GPS settings in the phone and set all the permissions. But still I am facing this.

***/*Java code*/***

```
public class GpsLocationTracker extends Service implements LocationListener
{


private Context mContext;
private boolean isGpsEnabled = false;
private boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
private boolean canGetLocation = false;
private Location mLocation;
private double mLatitude;
private double mLongitude;
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATE = 10;
private static final long MIN_TIME_FOR_UPDATE = 60000;
private LocationManager mLocationManager;

/**
 * mContext constructor of the class
 */
public GpsLocationTracker(Context mContext)
{

    this.mContext = mContext;
    getLocation();
}


/**
 * method to finding the location
 */
public Location getLocation() 
{

    try {

        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        /*getting status of the gps*/
        isGpsEnabled = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        /*getting status of network provider*/
        isNetworkEnabled = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGpsEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled)
        {
            /*no location provider enabled*/
            System.out.println("Gps and Network not enabled");
        } 
        else 
        {

            this.canGetLocation = true;

            /*getting location from network provider*/
            /* if (isNetworkEnabled) {

                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_FOR_UPDATE, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATE, this);

                if (mLocationManager != null) {

                    mLocation = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                    if (mLocation != null) {

                        mLatitude = mLocation.getLatitude();

                        mLongitude = mLocation.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
             }*/
            /*if gps is enabled then get location using gps*/
            if (isGpsEnabled) 
            {
                if (mLocation == null) 
                {
                    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_FOR_UPDATE, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATE, this);

                    if (mLocationManager != null) 
                    {
                        mLocation = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        System.out.println("location gps"+mLocation);
                        if (mLocation != null) 
                        {
                            mLatitude = mLocation.getLatitude();

                            mLongitude = mLocation.getLongitude();
                             System.out.println("Latitude gps"+mLatitude);
                                System.out.println("longitude gps"+mLongitude);
                        }

                    }
                }

                }
          // }
     }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return mLocation;
}

/**
 * call this function to stop using gps in our application
 */
public void stopUsingGps() 
{

    if (mLocationManager != null) 
    {

        mLocationManager.removeUpdates(GpsLocationTracker.this);

    }
}

/**
 * @return latitude <p/> function to get latitude
 */
public double getLatitude()
{

    if (mLocation != null) 
    {

        mLatitude = mLocation.getLatitude();
    }
    return mLatitude;
}

/**
 * @return longitude function to get longitude
 */
public double getLongitude()
{

    if (mLocation != null) 
    {

        mLongitude = mLocation.getLongitude();

    }

    return mLongitude;
}

/**
 * @return to check gps or wifi is enabled or not
 */
public boolean canGetLocation() 
{

    return this.canGetLocation;
}

/**
 * function to prompt user to open settings to enable gps
 */
public void showSettingsAlert()
{

    AlertDialog.Builder mAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(mContext, R.style.AppTheme));

    mAlertDialog.setTitle("Gps Disabled");

    mAlertDialog.setMessage("gps is not enabled . do you want to enable ?");

    mAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("settings", new OnClickListener() 
    {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent mIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(mIntent);
        }
    });

    mAlertDialog.setNegativeButton("cancle", new OnClickListener()
    {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dialog.cancel();

        }
    });

    final AlertDialog mcreateDialog = mAlertDialog.create();
    mcreateDialog.show();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Comment: you are testing with the real device?

Comment: Have you given permissions in manifest ?

Comment: yes.I tested using real device and also gave permissions in manifest.In network provider its working fine

Comment: @user3228311, Ok, that means your code is fine, You must be testing inside room, I suggest you to go outside, below open sky or near window. Because GPS_PROVIDER requires open sky field. :)

Comment: OK.now i am testing inside the room.Is it possible to get latlong inside the room?

Comment: @user3228311 It is a bit difficult.  However you can use fake gps applications in the market

Comment: @user3228311, the only way to check inside the room is NETWORK_PROVIDER